# Updates using WSUS instead of Microsoft Windows website

Tags: c#, windows-update

I want to search wsus or a local folder for the updates instead of microsoft. Any ideas? Here is what I have but this only connects to Windows Updates using the internet.

### UPDATE

I FOUND OUT THE ANSWER WITH THE VBS script. The ssdefault server is set by group policy. So if I apply group policy to the WUA then I was able to make automatic updates based on WSUS.
For the group policy steps go to: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512630.aspx 
Make sure that specify intranet service location is pointing to your wsus server. In our case it was 
http://wsus for both the statistics and update service.You also have to enable automatic updates like the article describes.

If you are going to use the c# code below make sure to change UpdateSearchResult.Online = false; if ypu want to search WSUS instead of Online.Thanks for anybody that might have tried to answer this question.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WUApiLib;//this is required to use the Interfaces given by microsoft. 

//todo check isassigned and guids for the following and include them in the search.
//http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff357803(VS.85).aspx
//determine the size of the  update in mb

namespace MSHWindowsUpdateAgent
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
            Console.WriteLine("Analyzing your needs");
            UpdatesAvailable();
            if (NeedsUpdate())
            {
                EnableUpdateServices();//enables everything windows need in order to make an update
                InstallUpdates(DownloadUpdates());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There are no updates for your computer at this time.");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to finalize the process");
            Console.Read();
        }
        //this is my first try.. I can see the need for abstract classes here...
        //but at least it gives most people a good starting point.
        public static  void InstalledUpdates()
        {
            UpdateSession UpdateSession = new UpdateSession();
            IUpdateSearcher UpdateSearchResult = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
            UpdateSearchResult.Online = true;//checks for updates online
            ISearchResult SearchResults = UpdateSearchResult.Search("IsInstalled=1 AND IsHidden=0");
            //for the above search criteria refer to 
            //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386526(v=VS.85).aspx
            //Check the remakrs section
            Console.WriteLine("The following updates are available");
            foreach (IUpdate x in SearchResults.Updates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Title);
            }
        }
        public static void UpdatesAvailable()
        {
            UpdateSession UpdateSession = new UpdateSession();
            IUpdateSearcher UpdateSearchResult = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
            UpdateSearchResult.Online = true;//checks for updates online
            ISearchResult SearchResults = UpdateSearchResult.Search(
            "IsInstalled=0 AND IsPresent=0 and IsAssigned=1  AND CategoryIDs contains 'E6CF1350-C01B-414D-A61F-263D14D133B4' OR CategoryIDs contains '0FA1201D-4330-4FA8-8AE9-B877473B6441'  ");
            //for the above search criteria refer to 
            //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386526(v=VS.85).aspx
            //Check the remakrs section

            foreach (IUpdate x in SearchResults.Updates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Title);
            }
        }
        public static bool NeedsUpdate()
        {
            UpdateSession UpdateSession = new UpdateSession();
            IUpdateSearcher UpdateSearchResult = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
            UpdateSearchResult.Online = true;//checks for updates online
            ISearchResult SearchResults = UpdateSearchResult.Search("IsInstalled=0 AND IsPresent=0 and IsAssigned=1  AND CategoryIDs contains 'E6CF1350-C01B-414D-A61F-263D14D133B4' OR CategoryIDs contains '0FA1201D-4330-4FA8-8AE9-B877473B6441'");
            //for the above search criteria refer to 
            //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386526(v=VS.85).aspx
            //Check the remakrs section
            if (SearchResults.Updates.Count > 0)
                return true;
            else return false;
        }
        public static UpdateCollection DownloadUpdates()
        {
            UpdateSession UpdateSession = new UpdateSession();
            IUpdateSearcher SearchUpdates = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
      
            ISearchResult UpdateSearchResult = SearchUpdates.Search("IsInstalled=0 AND IsPresent=0 and IsAssigned=1  AND CategoryIDs contains 'E6CF1350-C01B-414D-A61F-263D14D133B4' OR CategoryIDs contains '0FA1201D-4330-4FA8-8AE9-B877473B6441'");
            UpdateCollection UpdateCollection = new UpdateCollection();
            //Accept Eula code for each update
            for (int i = 0; i < UpdateSearchResult.Updates.Count; i++)
            {
                IUpdate Updates = UpdateSearchResult.Updates[i];
                if (Updates.EulaAccepted == false)
                {
                    Updates.AcceptEula();
                }
                UpdateCollection.Add(Updates);
            }
            //Accept Eula ends here
            //if it is zero i am not sure if it will trow an exception -- I havent tested it.
            if (UpdateSearchResult.Updates.Count > 0)
            {
                UpdateCollection DownloadCollection = new UpdateCollection();
                UpdateDownloader Downloader = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader();

                for (int i = 0; i < UpdateCollection.Count; i++)
                {
                    DownloadCollection.Add(UpdateCollection[i]);
                }

                Downloader.Updates = DownloadCollection;
                Console.WriteLine("Downloading Updates... This may take several minutes.");


                IDownloadResult DownloadResult = Downloader.Download();

                UpdateCollection InstallCollection = new UpdateCollection();
                for (int i = 0; i < UpdateCollection.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (DownloadCollection[i].IsDownloaded)
                    {
                        InstallCollection.Add(DownloadCollection[i]);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Download Finished");
                return InstallCollection;
            }
            else
                return UpdateCollection;
        }
        public static void InstallUpdates(UpdateCollection DownloadedUpdates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Installing updates now...");
            UpdateSession UpdateSession = new UpdateSession();
            UpdateInstaller InstallAgent = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller() as UpdateInstaller;
            InstallAgent.Updates = DownloadedUpdates;
            
            //Starts a synchronous installation of the updates.
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386491(v=VS.85).aspx#methods
            if (DownloadedUpdates.Count > 0)
            {
                IInstallationResult InstallResult = InstallAgent.Install();
                if (InstallResult.ResultCode == OperationResultCode.orcSucceeded)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Updates installed succesfully");
                    if (InstallResult.RebootRequired == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Reboot is required for one of more updates.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Updates failed to install do it manually");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The computer that this script was executed is up to date");
            }

        }
        public static void EnableUpdateServices()
        {
            IAutomaticUpdates updates = new AutomaticUpdates();
            if (!updates.ServiceEnabled)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not all updates services where enabled. Enabling Now" + updates.ServiceEnabled);
                updates.EnableService();
                Console.WriteLine("Service enable success");
            }
   

        }

    }
}
```

## Running the following script help me determine the configuration of WUA

```
'---------------------START-----------------------

' Einstellungen für die automatischen Updates
' http://www.wsus.de/
' Version 1.05.04.1
' Translated quick and dirty into English Marco Biagini
' mbiagini@ehsd.cccounty.us
'--------------------------------------------
On Error Resume Next

Set objWshNet = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")

const HKCU = &H80000001
const HKLM = &H80000002

strDefComputer = lcase(objWshNet.ComputerName)

Set oArgs = WScript.Arguments
If oArgs.Count = 0 Then
 strComputer = InputBox("Please enter the name or IP address of the Computer that you want to check WSUS settings", "Automatic Updates", strDefComputer)
Else
 strComputer = oArgs(0)
End If

If strComputer = "" Then
 WScript.Quit
End if

strComputer = lcase(strComputer)
if left(strComputer,2)="\\" then
 strComputer=right(strComputer,(len(strComputer)-2))
end if

Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
 msgbox "Unable to connect to:" & VBCRLF & VBCRLF & "     " & strComputer & VBCRLF, vbCritical, "Communication Error"
 WScript.Quit
End If

Resultmsg = "**** Results of WUA Settings ****" & VBCRLF & VBCRLF

strMsg = "No Auto Update:  "
strKeyPath = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
strValueName = "NoAutoUpdate"
If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
 oReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
 Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & GetNoAutoUpdate(dwValue) & VBCRLF & VBCRLF
Else
 Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Automatic Updates are not configured" & VBCRLF & VBCRLF
End If

strMsg = "Use WU Server:  "
strKeyPath = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
strValueName = "UseWUServer"
If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
 oReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
 Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & GetUseWUServer(dwValue) & VBCRLF

 If dwValue = "1" Then
  strMsg = "  - WSUS Server:  "
  strKeyPath = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate"
  strValueName = "WUServer"
  If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
   oReg.GetStringValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue
   Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & strValue & VBCRLF
  Else
   Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Automatic Updates are not configured" & VBCRLF
  End If
 
  strMsg = "  - WU Status Server:  "
  strKeyPath = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate"
  strValueName = "WUStatusServer"
  If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
   oReg.GetStringValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue
   Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & strValue & VBCRLF
  Else
   Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Automatic Updates are not configured" & VBCRLF
  End If
 Else
  Resultmsg = Resultmsg & VBCRLF
 End If
Else
 Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Automatic Updates are not configured" & VBCRLF
 Resultmsg = Resultmsg & "  - Client configured to receive Updates from windowsupdate.microsoft.com" & VBCRLF
End If

strMsg = "  - TargetGroup:  "
strKeyPath = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate"
strValueName = "TargetGroup"
 If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
  oReg.GetStringValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue
  Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & strValue & VBCRLF & VBCRLF
 Else
  Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Value not configured" & VBCRLF & VBCRLF
End If

strMsg = "AU Options:  "
strKeyPath = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
strValueName = "AUOptions"
If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
 oReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
 Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & GetAUOptions(dwValue) & VBCRLF

 If dwValue = "4" Then
  strMsg = "  - Scheduled Install Day:  "
  strKeyPath = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
  strValueName = "ScheduledInstallDay"
  If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
   oReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
   Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & getday(dwValue) & VBCRLF
  Else
   Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Value not configured" & VBCRLF
  End If
 
  strMsg = "  - Planned Installation Time:  "
  strKeyPath = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
  strValueName = "ScheduledInstallTime"
  If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
   oReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
   Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & dwValue &":00 - 24 hours 4:00 is 4 AM, 16:00 is 4 PM" & VBCRLF
  Else
   Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Value not configured" & VBCRLF
  End If
 Else
   Resultmsg = Resultmsg & VBCRLF
 End If

Else
 Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Value is not configured" & VBCRLF
 strMsg = "  - Benutzerdefinierte Einstellung:  "
 strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update"
 strValueName = "AUOptions"
 If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
  oReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
  Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & GetAUOptions(dwValue) & VBCRLF

  If dwValue = "4" Then
   strMsg = "    - ScheduledInstallDay:  "
   strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update"
   strValueName = "ScheduledInstallDay"
   If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
    oReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
    Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & getday(dwValue) & VBCRLF
   Else
    Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Automatic Updates are not configured" & VBCRLF
   End If
 
   strMsg = "    - ScheduledInstallTime:  "
   strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update"
   strValueName = "ScheduledInstallTime"
   If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
    oReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
    Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & dwValue &":00" & VBCRLF
   Else
    Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Automatic Updates are not configured" & VBCRLF
   End If
  Else
    Resultmsg = Resultmsg & VBCRLF
  End If

 Else
  Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Not configured" & VBCRLF
 End If
End If

strMsg = "  - NoAUShutdownOption:  "
strKeyPath = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
strValueName = "NoAUShutdownOption"
If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
 oReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
 Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & GetNoAUShutdownOption(dwValue) & VBCRLF & VBCRLF
Else
 Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Value not configured" & VBCRLF & VBCRLF
End If

strMsg = "AutoInstallMinorUpdates:  "
strKeyPath = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
strValueName = "AutoInstallMinorUpdates"
If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
 oReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
 Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & GetAutoInstallMinorUpdates(dwValue) & VBCRLF & VBCRLF
Else
 Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Value is not configured" & VBCRLF & VBCRLF
End If

strMsg = "DetectionFrequency:  "
strKeyPath = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
strValueName = "DetectionFrequency"
 If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
  oReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
  Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg &"Every " & dwValue &" Hours to search for updates"& VBCRLF
 Else
   Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Value is not configured"& VBCRLF
 End If

strMsg = "RebootRelaunchTimeout:  "
strKeyPath = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
strValueName = "RebootRelaunchTimeout"
 If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
  oReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
  Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & dwValue &" Minutes to wait until system restart"& VBCRLF
 Else
   Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Value is not configured" & VBCRLF
 End If

strMsg = "RebootWarningTimeout:  "
strKeyPath = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
strValueName = "RebootWarningTimeout"
 If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
  oReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
  Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & dwValue &" Minutes wait until system restart"& VBCRLF
 Else
   Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Value not configured" & VBCRLF
End If

strMsg = "NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers:  "
strKeyPath = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
strValueName = "NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers"
If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
 oReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
 Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & GetNoAutoReboot(dwValue) & VBCRLF
Else
 Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Value not configured" & VBCRLF
 Resultmsg = Resultmsg & "  - Default: User will be presented with a 5 minutes countdown" & VBCRLF
End If

strMsg = "RescheduleWaitTime:  "
strKeyPath = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
strValueName = "RescheduleWaitTime"
If RegValueExists(strKeyPath, strValueName) Then
 oReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
 If dwValue = "0" Then Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Value not configured: " & dwValue & VBCRLF & VBCRLF End If
 If dwValue = "1" Then Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & dwValue &" Minute" & VBCRLF & VBCRLF End If
 If dwValue > "1" and dwValue < "61" Then Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & dwValue &" Minutes" & VBCRLF & VBCRLF End If
 If dwValue > "60" Then Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Invalid Value" & dwValue & VBCRLF & VBCRLF End If
Else
 Resultmsg = Resultmsg & strMsg & "Not Configured" & VBCRLF & VBCRLF
End If


Resultmsg = Resultmsg & "http://www.wsus.de" & VBCRLF & "Die Infoseite zu Windows Server Updates Services"

MsgBox Resultmsg,,strComputer

set oReg = nothing


Function GetNoAutoUpdate(Index)
 Select Case Index
  Case 0 GetNoAutoUpdate = "0 - Auto Update applied by GPO"
  Case 1 GetNoAutoUpdate = "1 - No Auto Update is applied by GPO"
  Case Else GetNoAutoUpdate = "Invalid Entry"
 End select
End Function

Function GetUseWUServer(Index)
 Select Case Index
  Case 0 GetUseWUServer = "0 - Client is configured to receive updates from windowsupdate.microsoft.com"
  Case 1 GetUseWUServer = "1 - Client is configured to receive updates from your WSUS Server"
  Case Else GetUseWUServer = "Invalid Entry"
 End select
End Function

Function GetDay(Index)
 Select Case Index
  Case "0" GetDay = "Every Day"
  Case "1" GetDay = "Every Sunday"
  Case "2" GetDay = "Every Monday"
  Case "3" GetDay = "Every Tuesday"
  Case "4" GetDay = "Every Wednesday"
  Case "5" GetDay = "Every Thursday"
  Case "6" GetDay = "Every Friday"
  Case "7" GetDay = "Every Saturday"
  Case Else GetDay = "Invalid Entry"
 End select
End Function

Function GetAUOptions(Index)
 Select Case Index
  Case "0" GetAUOptions = "0"
  Case "1" GetAUOptions = "1 - Deaktiviert in den Benutzereinstellungen"
  Case "2" GetAUOptions = "2 - Notify before download and Install."
  Case "3" GetAUOptions = "3 - Autom. Download, notify before installation."
  Case "4" GetAUOptions = "4 - Autom. Download, install according to GPO settings."
  Case "5" GetAUOptions = "5 - Allow Local Administator installation and manual configuration."
  case Else GetAUOptions = "Invalid Entry"
 End select
End Function

Function GetNoAUShutdownOption(Index)
 Select Case Index
  Case 0 GetNoAUShutdownOption = "0 - 'Updates are being installed and system will be restarted' user ill be notified"
  Case 1 GetNoAUShutdownOption = "1 - 'Updates are being installed and system will be restarted' user will NOT be notified"
  Case Else GetNoAUShutdownOption = "Invalid Entry"
 End select
End Function

Function GetAutoInstallMinorUpdates(Index)
 Select Case Index
  Case 0 GetAutoInstallMinorUpdates = "0 - Automatic updates are not immediately installed"
  Case 1 GetAutoInstallMinorUpdates = "1 - Automatic updates are immediately installed"
  Case Else GetAutoInstallMinorUpdates = "Invalid Entry"
 End select
End Function

Function GetNoAutoReboot(Index)
 Select Case Index
  Case "0" GetNoAutoReboot = "0 - User Countdown of 5 Minutes"
  Case "1" GetNoAutoReboot = "1 - User will be notified before a system restart"
  case Else GetNoAutoReboot = "Invalid Entry"
 End select
End Function

Function RegValueExists(sRegKey, sRegValue)
  sRegKey = Trim(sRegKey)
  sRegValue = LCase(Trim(sRegValue))
  ' init value
  RegValueExists = False
  If oReg.EnumValues(HKLM, sRegKey, aValueNames, aValueTypes) = 0 Then
    If Not IsNull(aValueNames) Then
      For i = 0 To UBound(aValueNames)
        If LCase(aValueNames(i)) = sRegValue Then
          RegValueExists = True
        End If
      Next
    End If
  End If
End Function

Function RegKeyExists(sRegKey)
  sRegKey = Trim(sRegKey)
  If oReg.EnumValues(HKLM, sRegKey, aValueNames, aValueTypes) = 0 Then
    RegKeyExists = True
  Else
    RegKeyExists = False
  End If
End Function

'---------------------END-----------------------
```

Comment: I just discovered this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387280(v=VS.85).aspx but how do I set the ssManagedServer? I am currently working on that.

Comment: Another thing i just discovered: When I do:        Console.WriteLine(UpdateSearchResult.ServerSelection.ToString()); the result is ssDefault. Which I found out that: ssDefault
Used only by IUpdateSearcher. Indicates that the search call should search the default server.

The default server used by the Windows Update Agent (WUA) is the same as ssMangagedServer if the computer is set up to have a managed server. If the computer is not been set up to have a managed server, WUA uses the first update service for which the IsRegisteredWithAU property of IUpdateService is set to true

Comment: How get all computers (list) that use WUA - WSUS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a simple c# app that pulls all the updates from a local server named **SRV1** been using it only on windows 7 systems.  It uses ASP.NET 3.5 which is by default installed by Windows 7.

Simply change the **SRV1** in the source to your local wsus server.

Source code can be found [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=2c642e51fefe4846&resid=2C642E51FEFE4846!118&parid=root)

Comment: I downloaded the project but did not see any code that would imply that anything would be downloaded from wsus.